# I can't cahnge my ubuntu cursor and solution berfore can't help me

Tags: themes, cursor

All defaults cursors is OK, but if i try download and set something form the internet, it will usual black/white-dmz cursor. Yes, I tries to change default cursor in txt document, but doesn't work, help me, please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.